# Change bootstrap navbar sidebar a element color on first-child

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

The following CSS successfully changes the first child's background color and border of my sidebar nav:

```
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child{
  border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;      
  background: #2980b9;        
}
```

This CSS is where I need help. I want the first child's font color on the a element to be white, but this code changes all the font colors to white for the whole sidebar.

```
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li > a:first-child{
  color:  #ffffff;
}
```

My html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>      
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ><a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}">Dashboard
        <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
        <li ><a href="{{ route('admin.athletes') }}">Athletes
        <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>        
        <li ><a href="{{ route('admin.new_athlete') }}">Create Athlete
        <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the first child's font color on the a element to be white, but this code changes all the font colors to white for the whole sidebar.
>
> ```
> nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li > a:first-child{
> ```

Of course it does, because now you are not selecting the LI that is the first child of its parent any more, but the A that is the first child of its LI parent - and that is of course all of them, *because* you are selecting *all* LI.

You need to keep selecting the first LI element, and then the link(s) inside of that:

```
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child > a{
```

Comment: perfect, makes sense. Thanks for explaining.